# How can i open an image in it's full size in UWP

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin, uwp

I am working on a chat app:

[image: Chat]

If the user taps on an image, it will show in full size. The following method is called:

**Handle_Tapped()**:

```
void Handle_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Image image = sender as Image;
            string filePath = String.Empty;

            filePath = image.Source as FileImageSource;
            Eva3Toolkit.CommonUtils.openImage(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Which calls (depending on the OS):

**`openImage()` in Android**:

```
public void openImage(string filePath)
    {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        sendIntent.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file:" + filePath), "image/*");
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(sendIntent, "Bild öffnen..."));
    }
```

**`openImage()` in iOS**:

```
public void openImage(string filePath)
    {
        var firstController = ((UIApplicationDelegate)(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate)).Window.RootViewController.ChildViewControllers[0].ChildViewControllers[1].ChildViewControllers[0];
        var navcontroller = firstController as UINavigationController;
        var docIC = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(new NSUrl(filePath, true));
        docIC.Delegate = new DocInteractionC(navcontroller);
        docIC.PresentPreview(true);
    }
```

Now I want to create a method `openImage()` in UWP, but I don't know know. I know that I will most likely have to work with the image as a `StorageFile` instead of the path because only a StorageFile grants me permission to open the image.

Is there a way to open the image in full size in UWP? I highly prefer to not create a new view for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Launcher` can open a file with the program that is assigned to the file:

```
public async void openImageAsync(string filePath)
    {
        StorageFile storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
        await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(storageFile);
    }
```

For my situation it's working that I use `filePath` because the files are in a local folder.

The output looks like this:

[image]